# Image appears then disappears

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqc0Lfkt/)

I need to have my image inside 2 divs, why does it appear and then disappear?

I need it so that it's always on screen.

```
<div class="ad-container">
<div class="ad-item">
        <img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The class names that you are using are being hidden by the jsFiddle iframe style.

Answer (score 0):

Panthro,

Check and make sure there is no Javascript and any other code manipulating the classes: ad-container and ad-item.

The snippet of code you provided in the fiddle looks fine to me. There must be other code manipulating those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ad` from the class names. JSfiddle blocks the content related to ads similar to AdBlock functionality.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/qqc0Lfkt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I was able to solve it by **turning off my adblock** for the page.

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS must be causing the issue, check it or post what it is here.

Comment: There is no CSS! Check the fiddle.